# Using STL algorithms on 2D vectors to extract the first column

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, transform

I'm trying to learn to use more of the STL algorithms. I'm having trouble seeing if there is an more standard way of writing the following code.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> myVec;
std::vector<std::string> myInnerVec;
for(int y=0;y < myVec.size();y++){
    myInnerVec.emplace_back(myVec[y][0]);
}
```

Here i'm extracting the first column from the vector myVec and placing it into myInnerVec. Can this code be improved upon with any STL magic?

Comment: cant you store `myVec` transposed? Looping over `myVec[y][0]` isnt the most cache-friendly.

Comment: Do you really need a *copy* of the first column?

Comment: Wont that require a similar loop? I would like to store myVec as is so i can extract rows by just returning myVec[y]

Comment: @Freebi32 do you need this to be a jagged array, i.e., have the option that each column can have a different size?

Comment: the loop would look similar but not jump all over the place in memory like this one. The biggest plus for vector is data-locality, but as vectors use heap allocations a `vector<vector<T>>` does not have data-locality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can use the standard algorithm `std::transform`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v =
    {
        { "A", "B", "C" },
        { "D", "E", "F" }
    };

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>::size_type column;

    auto l = [&column = column]( const auto &row )
    {
        return row[column];
    };

    column = 0;

    std::vector<std::string> v1;

    v1.reserve( v.size() );

    std::transform( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), std::back_inserter( v1 ), l );

    for ( const auto &item : v1 ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    column = 1;

    std::transform( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), std::begin( v1 ), l );

    for ( const auto &item : v1 ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
A D 
B E
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. `std::transform` should do what you want
(untested code):

```
transform(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), 
    back_insert_iterator<vector<string>>(myInnerVec), 
    [](const vector<string> &v) {return v[0];});
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a possibility:

```cpp
std::transform(cbegin(myVec), cend(myvec), std::back_inserter(myInnerVex), [] (const auto &row) {return row[0];});
```

Note that you should call `myInnerVex.reserve(myVec.size());` beforehand. Alternatively, you could write an own iterator, that holds an iterator and always returns `*it[0]`.